# Mallet sources to eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Please, i want to know how to import this project (mallet-2.0-7) to eclipse:

```
 http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/download.php
```

I tried several times but without results. There are always error in the package tree and sometimes, when i try to run:

```
 TrainHMM.java in package cc.mallet.examples;
```

I have the message: selection does not contain a main type.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: In link there are described hot to install Mallet. I think first need to download zip, unzipped and builded with ant. The eclipse install don't work me.

Answer (score 1):

Import the mallet project: 
New->Project->Java Project From Existing Ant Buildfile

Comment: I tried and failed to import the mallet package to eclipse under Win7-64bit. Then I move to Ubuntu and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have any eclipse meta file so we can import it directly in eclipse
Create two files in that folder with following entry.

1. `.project`

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <projectDescription>
       <name>mallet-2.0.7</name>
       <comment></comment>
       <projects>
       </projects>
       <buildSpec>
           <buildCommand>
               <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
               <arguments>
               </arguments>
           </buildCommand>
       </buildSpec>
       <natures>
           <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
       </natures>
   </projectDescription>`
2. `.classpath`

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <classpath>
       <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
       <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
       <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/bsh.jar"/>
       <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/grmm-deps.jar"/>
       <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jdom-1.0.jar"/>
       <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jgrapht-0.6.0.jar"/>
       <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/junit-4.5.jar"/>
       <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jwnl-1.3.jar"/>
       <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/mallet-deps.jar"/>
       <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/mtj-0.9.9.jar"/>
       <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/openjgraph.jar"/>
       <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/trove-2.0.2.jar"/>
       <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
   </classpath>`
3. In eclipse use `File > import > Existing project into workspace`.
4. done